# media query for android with ionic

Tags: android, html, css, ionic-framework

I am using ionic 1 to create an app home page. I want it to suit for all sizes for android.

However, the page icon and word looks off in big screen such as & inch tablet and only looks fine in 5 inch.

How shall I do to make it suit for all screen sizes?

my html

```
  <div id="row2" class="row">
    <a class="col" href="#/app/racing">
      <div class="colwrapper">
        <i class="material-icons">&#xE06D;</i>
        <span>Racing</span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="col" href="#/app/gym">
      <div class="colwrapper">
        <i class="material-icons">&#xE8B6;</i>
        <span>Gym</span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="col" href="#/app/golf">
      <div class="colwrapper">
        <i class="ion-stats-bars"></i>
        <span>Golf</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="row3" class="row">
    <a class="col" href="#/app/pool">
      <div class="colwrapper">
        <i class="icon ion-medkit"></i>
        <span>Pool</span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="col" href="#/app/Futsal">
      <div class="colwrapper">
        <i class="material-icons">&#xE152;</i>
        <span>Futsal</span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="col" href="#/app/tennis">
      <div class="colwrapper">
        <i class="material-icons">&#xE417;</i>
        <span>Tennis</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
#row2, #row3{
  height: 20%;
  min-height: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}
#row2 .col .colwrapper, #row3 .col .colwrapper{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 55%;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
#row2 .col .colwrapper i, #row3 .col .colwrapper i{
  font-size: 20px;   
}
#row2 .col img, #row3 .col img{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 75%;
  width: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
#row2 .col span, #row3 .col span{
  display: block;
}
#row2 .col:first-child{
  background-color: #3f56a8;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
#row2 .col:nth-child(1n){
  background-color: #3f56a8;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
#row2 .col:last-child{
  background-color: #3f56a8;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
#row3 .col:first-child{
  background-color: #5e97d1;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
#row3 .col:nth-child(1n){
  background-color: #5e97d1;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
#row3 .col:last-child{
  background-color: #5e97d1;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Please advice how to do it.
I used to try with media query but seems no effect.

```
    @media (max-width:413px) and (min-width:321px) {

#row2 .col .colwrapper i, #row3 .col .colwrapper i{
      font-size: 20px;   
    }
}
```

I want the font and the icon always keeps center and if the size of screen is larger, the font and icon needs to be larger.

[picture shown as below for 7 inch tablets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbWlA.png)

Comment: Your media query has an extra brace.  Try this `@media (max-width:413px) and (min-width:321px) {

#row2 .col .colwrapper i, #row3 .col .colwrapper i{
      font-size: 20px;   
    }
}`

Comment: @Ihazkode Unfortunately it does not work.